# IntelliJ Scala not recognizing Scala symbols ('foo)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ Scala's debugger, you can open a window to evaluate expressions (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>)

However, it always fails as long as I have Scala symbols in the expression (i.e., 'foobar), saying:

`result = Literal has null value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug. It is fixed now, so all should work in the next version of the scala plugin.

You can use bugtracker for this kind of questions: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-6999

Comment: What release is this in?